# Regex pattern which, if followed by a dot, may repeat an arbitrary number of times

Tags: c#, regex

For the sake of ease let's say I have some pattern:

```
^[a-zA-Z_]{1,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,39}$
```

So this would match `foo`, or `_foo1` Or any similar string up to 40 characters.

Now what I need is to make it so that if there is a dot and ONLY if there is a dot, that pattern may be repeated any number of times.

```
Matching:

foo
foo.foo
foo.bar._foobar
<30 characters>.<30 characters>


not matching:
foo.
<some 41 character string not containing a dot>
```

My attempt was: `^([a-zA-Z_]{1,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,39})[\.]?(?<=\1)*$`

But that just appears to break the whole thing...

Comment: Try adding `(?:\.[_A-Za-z]){1,29})*` or alike: `^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,39}(?:\.[_A-Za-z]{1,29})*$`

Comment: Thank you. Question got closed pointing to a somewhat similar questions whose answer was `+`, and I know the answer isn't this simple for my case lol.

Yours work.